# Is it possible to set a transparency on a Google Chart dynamic icon?

Tags: google-visualization

I'm calling this url from Google Charts to place a custom icon on my Google map.
http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_bubble_icon_text_small&chld=home|bbT|HC|52B552|000000

In order to make my map more readable on a mobile browser, I'd like to set the transparency of the returned image, but I can't seem to find a way to do so. This Google Chart api page, http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/chart_params.html states that I can specify a value in the 00 - FF range, but when I try adding a value to my original url, http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_bubble_icon_text_small&chld=home|bbT|HC|52B552AA|000000, it returns a 404 error.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible.
You need to add chf=bg,s,FF000033 (Or some other color and alpha) that you want for the background
http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_bubble_icon_text_small&chf=bg,s,FF000033&chld=home|bbT|HC|52B552|000000

(Edit: I missed the last 0 in the URL. Now it is fixed)

Comment: Or did you mean transparency of the green color? Hmmm.. I'll check

Comment: I meant transparency of the green color. But using your example was able to get a working solution. http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_bubble_icon_text_small&chld=home|bbT|HC|52B552|000000&chf=a,s,52B55233. I changed the bg value to a to make the whole chart transparent. Thanks.

Comment: Aah, good. Since, from what I could read, the bubble chart does only accept a six digit color code = No alpha. (http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/apis/chart/docs/gallery/dynamic_icons.html#bubbles )